# Translating sendmail "MASQUERADE_AS" to postfix?

Tags: postfix, sendmail, sympa

Attempting to update an old server application (Sympa) to a newer OS. Fun.
 This includes related services (Sendmail to Postfix). More Fun.

Going through the sendmail.mc, we have

```
MASQUERADE_AS(`propersubdomain.domain.com')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_entire_domain')dnl
FEATURE(`allmasquerade')dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(localhost.localdomain)dnl
MASQUERADE_DOMAIN(actualhostname.domain.com)dnl
```

The actual hostname is being masqueraded as propersubdomain. The easy fix is changing the hostname. Can't be done.

In Postfix, I am not sure what is the equivalent behavior, or combinations. Inbound, I add the propersubdomain.domain.com to $mydestinations. Postfix will handle everything for propersubdomain.

Outbound, I am not sure. I believe $myorigin would be part of it. But I also see references to generic mapping? Or is it something else?

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a *long* time since I've had to use Sendmail, so I don't recall all the nuances of what `MASQUERADE_AS` does, but based on a reading of [the docs](https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/masquerading_relaying.html), I'm pretty sure `myorigin` is what you want ("The  domain  name  that locally-posted mail appears to come from, and that locally posted mail is delivered to").

There is no *direct* equivalent to `MASQUERADE_DOMAIN`, but as you suggested, [generic maps](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic) are what you want to use to achieve the same end result.

Finally, for complete masquerading, you may also want to look into `smtp_helo_name`.